# Compiling a Compound-Growth Rate For New Users on a Website

Tags: java

I am writing a program that will print out how many months it will take to grow a website from 1 billion users to 1.5 billion (and then 2 billion users) at a rate of 4% per a month. However, I am either having trouble with the math or breaking my code somewhere along the line.

Here is my code thus far:

```
 public class Exercise_432 {

     public static void main(String[] args) {

         double InitUsers = 1000000000;
         double NewUsers = 0;
         double rate = 0.04;

         System.out.println("How many months will it take to reach 1.5 billion users?\n" + 
                       "How many months will it take to reach 2 billion users?");

         for (int months = 1; months <= 1000; ++months)
         {
             NewUsers = InitUsers * Math.pow(1.0 + rate, months);
             if(NewUsers >= 1500000000) {

             }else if (NewUsers >= 2000000000){

             }

             System.out.printf("%d%n", months);
         }

     }

 }
```

Can anyone help me or at least point me in the right direction?

Thanks.

Comment: `for (int months = 1; months += 1; months < 1000)` this is wrong for loop syntax

Comment: Can't you just do the math directly? `2 / 1.5 = 1.04^m`, solve for `m`.

Comment: Take your principal of 1 billion * your rate, and store it in a variable. Use a while loop to do this, and each time while it's less than 1.5 or 2 billion, months++?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code, your `for loop` executes infinitely because the condition in it is always satisfied. You need to write correct condition. Even though you can use for loop, I personally prefer while loop when the condition is on a variable which is not getting incremented. In this particular problem, we have to increment `months` and check the condition on `users`. So a while loop would be better. See the below implementation

```
 public class Exercise_432 {

     public static void main(String[] args) {

       double users = 1; //Assuming it to be 1 Billion.
       double rate = 0.04; 
       int months = 0;

       while(users < 1.5) { //Stops looping if users count is >= 1.5 Billion
           users = users + (users * rate); //total new users = old users + new users for that month
           months++;
           if(users >= 1.5) {
               System.out.println(months);
           }
       }
       while(users < 2) { //Stops looping if users count is >= 2 Billion
           users = users + (users * rate);
           months++;
           if(users >= 2) {
               System.out.println(months);
           }
       }
     }
 }
```

Comment: How would I break the loop and print out the number of months once reached 1.5 billion users?

Comment: @justLearning See the conditions on users in the while loop I wrote.